How do i get a specific data from my database table to display use?
So i have these PHP code that supposed to retrieve specific data from MySQL database and i want to display the user type in my navigation bar. My problem is it doesn't really display the actual user type data from what is stored in my database.
My code so far: (mainpage.php):
<?php 
    include 'connect.php';

    // Fetch user type 'User'
    $fetchUser = "SELECT usertype FROM `tbluserprofile` WHERE usertype = 'User'";
    $queryUser = mysqli_query($connection, $fetchUser);
    
    // Fetch user type 'Trainer'
    $fetchTrainer = "SELECT usertype FROM `tbluserprofile` WHERE usertype = 'Trainer'";
    $queryTrainer = mysqli_query($connection, $fetchTrainer);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body class="flex flex-col min-h-screen">

<!-- navigation bar -->
<nav class="p-5 flex items-center justify-between text-black ">
    <div class="logo-div flex items-center ml-10">
        <h1 class="font-bold text-2xl ">GYMCHUM</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-link flex justify-between items-center space-x-4 ml-auto mr-10 font-bold p-2 text-l"></div>
    
    <div class="userProfile w-10 mr-28 flex items-center gap-3">
        <?php
        if (mysqli_num_rows($queryUser) > 0) {
            $rowUser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryUser);
            echo '<h1 class="font-bold text-xl bg-gray-200 pl-3 pr-3 rounded-full">' . $rowUser['usertype'] . '</h1>';
        } else if (mysqli_num_rows($queryTrainer) > 0) {
            $rowTrainer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryTrainer);
            echo '<h1 class="font-bold text-xl bg-gray-200 pl-3 pr-3 rounded-full">' . $rowTrainer['usertype'] . '</h1>';
        }
        ?>
        <img src="images/profile.png" class="user-profile ">
    </div>
</nav>

If you can help me with this, I'd really appreciate it.
Thank you very much.

You probably need something like $user_type = $connection->execute_query("SELECT usertype FROM tbluserprofile WHERE id=?",[$_SESSION['user_id']])->fetch_column();  and then just echo $user_type
